# clearInterval not clearing after setInterval parameter value is updated

Tags: reactjs, setinterval, clearinterval

In this game (got it from Youtube) the snake grows when it eats and it also speeds up. Everything works fine until the snake has at least one meal. At that point the Pause, Play buttons don't work at all and the the New Game button resets the position of the snake and the food location, but the game doesn't stop and the speed doesn't reset.

I know where the problem is (increaseSpeed()) but I don't know to fix it. If I remove the setInterval return from this function, every part of the game works fine except the speed never changes

```
const getRandomCoordinates = () => {
  let min = 1
  let max = 98
  let x = Math.floor((Math.random()*(max-min+1)+min)/2)*2
  let y = Math.floor((Math.random()*(max-min+1)+min)/2)*2
  return [x,y]
}

const initialState = {
  direction: 'RIGHT',
  speed: 200,
  food: getRandomCoordinates(),
  snakeDots: [
    [0,0],
    [2,0]
  ],
  message: ""
}

// GAMEBOARD COMPONENT
class GameBoard extends Component {

  state = initialState

  componentDidMount() {
    document.onkeydown = this.onKeyDown
  }

  componentDidUpdate() {
    this.checkIfOutOfBorders()
    this.checkIfCollapsed()
    this.checkIfEat()
  }

  playButton = () => {
    clearInterval(this.intervalId)
    this.intervalId = setInterval(this.moveSnake, this.state.speed)
  }

  pauseButton = () => {
    clearInterval(this.intervalId)
  }

  newGameButton = () => {
    this.setState(initialState)
    clearInterval(this.intervalId)
  }


  onKeyDown = (e) => {
    e = e || window.event;
    switch(e.keyCode) {
      case 38:
        this.setState({ direction: 'UP'})
        break
      case 40:
        this.setState({ direction: 'DOWN'})
        break
      case 37:
        this.setState({ direction: 'LEFT'})
        break
      case 39:
        this.setState({ direction: 'RIGHT'})
        break
      default:
    }
  }

  moveSnake = () => {
    let dots = [...this.state.snakeDots]
    let head = dots[dots.length - 1]

    switch (this.state.direction) {
      case 'RIGHT':
        head = [head[0] + 2, head[1]]
        break
      case 'LEFT':
        head = [head[0] - 2, head[1]]
        break
      case 'UP':
        head = [head[0], head[1] - 2]
        break
      case 'DOWN':
        head = [head[0], head[1] + 2]
        break
      default:
    }
    dots.push(head)
    dots.shift()
    this.setState({
      snakeDots: dots
    })
  }

  checkIfOutOfBorders = () => {
    let head = this.state.snakeDots[this.state.snakeDots.length - 1]
    if (head[0] >= 100 || head[1] >= 100 || head[0] < 0 || head[1] < 0) {
      this.onGameOver()
    }
  }

  checkIfCollapsed = () => {
    let snake = [...this.state.snakeDots]
    let head = snake[this.state.snakeDots.length - 1]
    snake.pop()
    snake.forEach(dot => {
      if (head[0] === dot[0] && head[1] === dot[1]) {
        this.onGameOver()
      }
    })
  }

  checkIfEat = () => {
    let head = this.state.snakeDots[this.state.snakeDots.length - 1]
    let food = this.state.food
    if (head[0] === food[0] && head[1] === food[1]) {
      this.setState({
        food: getRandomCoordinates()
      })
      this.growSnake()
      this.increaseSpeed()
    }
  }

  growSnake = () => {
    let newSnake = [...this.state.snakeDots]
    newSnake.unshift([])
    this.setState({
      snakeDots: newSnake
    })
  }

  increaseSpeed = () =>  {
    let speed = this.state.speed
    if (this.state.speed > 10) {
      this.setState({
        speed: speed - 10
      })
    }
    setInterval(this.moveSnake, this.state.speed)
  }

  onGameOver = () => {
    // alert(`Game over! You're snake length is ${this.state.snakeDots.length}`)
    this.newGameButton()
    console.log('over')

  }

  render () {
    return (
      <div className="console-container">
        <div className="game-area">
          <Snake snakeDots={ this.state.snakeDots } />
          <Food food={ this.state.food } />
        </div>
        <ControlPanel
          playButton={this.playButton}
          pauseButton={this.pauseButton}
          newGameButton={this.newGameButton}
          scoreboardMessage={this.scoreboardMessage}
        />
      </div>
    )
  }
}

export default GameBoard
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are 3 problems in the `increaseSpeed` method in this line :

`setInterval(this.moveSnake, this.state.speed)`;

1. You don't save the new interval ID
2. You use the old state value (because `setState` is async)
3. You don't clear previous interval

This should work :

```
  increaseSpeed = () =>  {
    let speed = this.state.speed
    if (this.state.speed > 10) {
      speed -= 10;
      this.setState({
        speed
      })
    }
    clearInterval(this.intervalId);
    this.intervalId = setInterval(this.moveSnake, speed);
  }
```

Comment: I tried this and it's the same. With clearInterval in this function everything works, but the speed doesn't increase. If i remove it then the original problems comes back as described

Comment: Just to be sur, in `setInterval ` I'm not using `this.state.speed`, you tried that ?

Comment: yes. I literally pasted in your code. For some reason once ``setInterval`` is updated by this function it cannot be cleared

Comment: My apologies. Your solution does work. The speak was just increasing so slowly, ,compared to what I was seeing, that I didn't notice the difference. Thanks!

Comment: Glad it helped. Happy coding